# Reporting quarterly changes for each department

Tags: java, beginner, array

This code works 100%, but I am trying to see if I can use a `for`-statement to make my second method less-cumbersome and more efficient instead of making so many variables.

I have to show the differences between each quarter for every department.

My array has 6 Departments and 4 Quarters.

```
import java.util.*;
public void setQuarter()
{
    final int DEPARTMENT = 6;
    final int QUARTER = 4;
    private static double [][] sales = new double [DEPARTMENT][QUARTER];
    Scanner  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < DEPARTMENT ; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < QUARTER; col++)
        {
            // This will input value into my array
            System.out.print(" \n What Were The Total Sales For Department : " + (row + 1 ) + " Quarter : " + (col + 1 ) + " = ");
            sales[row][col] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only thing that I could come up with, since I am new to Java and 2-D arrays.  I want to know if there is an easier way of getting the quarterly differences for each department.  I was told I could use a nested `for`-statement to subtract the elements in the 2-D array.  However, I have tried but I can't seem to get one done.  I am pretty sure the use of a nested `for`-statement would clean my code up quickly.  Can anyone help me out with this?

```
public void departmentdiff()
    {   
        double dept1Qrt1 = sales [0] [0];
        double dept2Qrt1 = sales [1] [0];
        double dept3Qrt1 = sales [2] [0];
        double dept4Qrt1 = sales [3] [0];
        double dept5Qrt1 = sales [4] [0];
        double dept6Qrt1 = sales [5] [0];
        double dept1Qrt2 = sales [0] [1];
        double dept2Qrt2 = sales [1] [1];
        double dept3Qrt2 = sales [2] [1];
        double dept4Qrt2 = sales [3] [1];
        double dept5Qrt2 = sales [4] [1];
        double dept6Qrt2 = sales [5] [1];
        double dept1Qrt3 = sales [0] [2];
        double dept2Qrt3 = sales [1] [2];
        double dept3Qrt3 = sales [2] [2];
        double dept4Qrt3 = sales [3] [2];
        double dept5Qrt3 = sales [4] [2];
        double dept6Qrt3 = sales [5] [2];
        double dept1Qrt4 = sales [0] [3];
        double dept2Qrt4 = sales [1] [3];
        double dept3Qrt4 = sales [2] [3];
        double dept4Qrt4 = sales [3] [3];
        double dept5Qrt4 = sales [4] [3];
        double dept6Qrt4 = sales [5] [3];
        double total1 = 0;
        double total2 = 0;
        double total3= 0;

        // Instructs User To Press Enter To Continue
        System.out.println(" \n \n \n Please Press Enter To Display The Department's Difference In Each Quarter ");
        // Scanner Type Waits For the "Enter" Input Before Proceeding
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        total1 = dept1Qrt1 - dept1Qrt2;
        total2 = dept1Qrt2 - dept1Qrt3;
        total3 = dept1Qrt3 - dept1Qrt4;
        System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
        System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");

        total1 = dept2Qrt1 - dept2Qrt2;
        total2 = dept2Qrt2 - dept2Qrt3;
        total3 = dept2Qrt3 - dept2Qrt4;
        System.out.println( " \n \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-2 is :");
        System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");

        total1 = dept3Qrt1 - dept3Qrt2;
        total2 = dept3Qrt2 - dept3Qrt3;
        total3 = dept3Qrt3 - dept3Qrt4;
        System.out.println( " \n \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-3 is :");
        System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");

        total1 = dept4Qrt1 - dept4Qrt2;
        total2 = dept4Qrt2 - dept4Qrt3;
        total3 = dept4Qrt3 - dept4Qrt4;
        System.out.println( " \n \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-4 is :");
        System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");

        total1 = dept5Qrt1 - dept5Qrt2;
        total2 = dept5Qrt2 - dept5Qrt3;
        total3 = dept5Qrt3 - dept5Qrt4;
        System.out.println( " \n \n  Quarterly Differences For Department-5 is :");
        System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");

        total1 = dept6Qrt1 - dept6Qrt2;
        total2 = dept6Qrt2 - dept6Qrt3;
        total3 = dept6Qrt3 - dept6Qrt4;
        System.out.println( " \n \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-6 is :");
        System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Refactoring should get you there

```
    total1 = dept1Qrt1 - dept1Qrt2;
    total2 = dept1Qrt2 - dept1Qrt3;
    total3 = dept1Qrt3 - dept1Qrt4;
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");
```

We're going to make it look worse for a moment...

```
    total1 = sales [0] [0]- sales [0] [1];
    total2 = sales [0] [1]- sales [0] [2];
    total3 = sales [0] [2]- sales [0] [3];
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");
```

Re arrange, so things line up better

```
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    total1 = sales [0] [0]- sales [0] [1];
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
    total2 = sales [0] [1]- sales [0] [2];
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
    total3 = sales [0] [2]- sales [0] [3];
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");
```

Inject a variable to represent the quarter

```
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    int quarter = 0;
    total1 = sales [0] [quarter]- sales [0] [quarter+1];
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 1 to Quarter : 2 The Difference Is ( " + total1 + " ) ");
    quarter = 1;
    total2 = sales [0] [quarter]- sales [0] [quarter+1];
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 2 to Quarter : 3 The Difference Is ( " + total2 + " ) ");
    quarter = 2;
    total3 = sales [0] [quarter]- sales [0] [quarter+1];
    System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : 3 to Quarter : 4 The Difference Is ( " + total3 + " ) ");
```

Now it should be obvious where the for loop falls out; note the introduction of "quarterNames", which is a lookup table (aka array) to make sure the spellings are correct in the strings; you need to do something to ensure that you don't confuse 1-based humans by printing 0-based identifiers.

```
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    for (int quarter = 0; quarter < 3; ++quarter {
        double total = sales [0] [quarter]- sales [0] [quarter+1];
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : " + quarterNames[quarter] + " to Quarter : " + quarterNames[quarter+1] + " The Difference Is ( " + total + " ) ");
    }
```

For more readability, use better variable names

```
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-1 is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    for (int thisQuarter = 0; thisQuarter < 3; ++thisQuarter {
        int nextQuarter = 1 + thisQuarter;

        double total = sales [0] [thisQuarter]- sales [0] [nextQuarter];
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : " + quarterNames[thisQuarter] + " to Quarter : " + quarterNames[nextQuarter] + " The Difference Is ( " + total + " ) ");
    }
```

Eliminate some magic numbers

```
    int thisDepartment = 0;
    System.out.println( " \n The Quarterly Differences For Department-" + departmentId[thisDepartment] + " is :");
    System.out.println( " ********************************************** ");
    for (int thisQuarter = 0; thisQuarter < QUARTER; ++thisQuarter {
        int nextQuarter = 1 + thisQuarter;

        double total = sales [thisDepartment] [thisQuarter]- sales [thisDepartment] [nextQuarter];
        System.out.println( " \n From Quarter : " + quarterNames[thisQuarter] + " to Quarter : " + quarterNames[nextQuarter] + " The Difference Is ( " + total + " ) ");
    }
```

At this point, it should be clear how to create a for loop that generates the report for each department.

BUT: more advanced programmers wouldn't do it this way.  Part of the reason that this is such a mess, is that you are storing each piece of data independently, and then trying to reconstruct the data relationships.

In this example, there are three (simple) abstractions.  There's the concept of a "quarter", there's the concept of a department - which has sales for each quarter, and there is the concept of a report, which tracks changes per quarter.

```
class Quarter {
    // this would normally be a date range, or a year/fiscal quarter pair, or something
    // for your simple example, it could even be an enum.
    int id;

    // These two methods, because it's important to get key semantics correct.
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object other);

    @Override
    int hashCode();
}

class Department {
    // Not going to define Sales.  In your example, it could just be a Double.
    Map<Quarter, Sales> = salesResults;
}

class Report {
    Quarter start;
    Quarter end;
}

List<Department> departments = new ArrayList();
List<Report> reports = new ArrayList();

for(Department department : departments) {
    for(Report report : reports) {
        double total = department.salesResults.get(report.start) - department.salesResults.get(report.end);
        // do something with the total
    }
}
```